# Is there a way to create a virtual environment with an earlier version of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I have `python 3.8` installed on my pc, but i need `3.7` for a specific task. When i try to set up a virtual environment via

```
virtualenv -p "my/path/to/python37.exe"
```

it calls the installer, so i am to install `py37` manually, but then it ends up with an error:

```
Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed
```

Is there a proper way to implement such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: `pyenv` easily supports this out of the box.

Comment: I rely on [PyCharm's virtualenv](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html); you can have a specific python version, with specific packages installed for each project.

Comment: Your error code is not related with with Python. That error related with Visiual Studio registry setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anaconda or miniconda (the lighter version of anaconda)? Having more python versions in different environments and switching between them is quite easy.

Comment: I ll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't installed Anaconda. If you want to have multiple different environments with pure Python you can do it like this:

1) Install the python versions that you want with the exe installer, ie Python 2.x.x, Python 3.7.x, Python 3.8.x etc, maybe inside a common folder like C:\Python

2) Then edit the System Variables path and pinpoint to the folder for the version you want to create a virtual environment. You need two entries here, one to python folder (for the python.exe) and one to the Scripts folder (for the pip.exe)

3) Open command prompt and hit python. You ll see that it's showing the apporpriate version. Install the virtual environment with "python -m venv name_of_env_you_want"

4) If you want to create a virtual environment with a different version change the paths

Comment: Thanks for respond. Python doesn't allow to install multiple versions globally

Comment: What do you mean? I have different versions installed at the same system. Uncheck the default options when you install the versions and do not add python to root, you are going to do it manually later to switch between the versions.

Also check this article, maybe it helps you? https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/